# How to create a conditional relationship in SQLAlchemy based on a relationship in the child object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I am trying to create a conditional relationship called **children_with_grandchild** on the **parent** object that only includes **child** objects that have at least one **grandchild**. I have a model like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


def setup():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    children = relationship('Child', lazy='joined')


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(ForeignKey('parent.id'))

    grandchildren = relationship('GrandChild', lazy='joined')


class GrandChild(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'grandchild'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(ForeignKey('child.id'))
```

What I have tried so far that hasn't worked is adding the following to the **Parent** class:

```
children_with_grandchild = relationship('Child',
                                        primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id==Child.parent_id,'
                                                    'Child.grandchildern.any())',
                                        lazy='joined')
```

Based on the error message I get when I tried this it appears that only columns are allowed to be used within the conditionals in the **primaryjoin** attribute and not relationships. So I also tried adding the following to the **Parent** class:

```
children_with_grandchild = relationship('Child',
                                        primaryjoin='and_(Parent.id==Child.parent_id,'
                                                    'Child.id==Grandchild.child_id)',
                                        lazy='joined')
```

However the error I get here when I query for a **Parent** record is:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: grandchild.child_id

This error appears to be caused by the inclusion of the **lazy='joined'** attribute because if I remove that it works fine. Problem is for query optimization I really need to load the **childern_with_grandchild** relationship in the initial query.

Given the following test data the relationship **children_with_grandchild** should contain only the **c1** child where the relationship **children** would contain both the **c1** and **c2** child objects.

```
>>> setup()
>>> session = Session()
>>> p = Parent(id=1)
>>> c1 = Child(id=1, parent_id=1)
>>> c2 = Child(id=2, parent_id=1)
>>> gc1 = GrandChild(id=1, child_id=1)
>>> session.add_all([p, c1, c2, gc1])
>>> session.commit()
>>> p = session.query(Parent).first()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you try something like just having `child` with a self relationship to `child`? keep two classes, a grandchild could just be a self relationship. you can add a `@property` on `parent` to `return self.child.children` . At least that's how I try to approach it, I don't see much use for a grand child class, if it is just a child of a child

Comment: @Busturdust Thank you for the comment. Examples of when the `grandchild` class might make sense is if `parent-child-grandchild` is a model for `project-jobs-workers` where each object would have different attributes. In this example the relationship I might want to build on the `project` object is `jobs` without a `worker` associated to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

On the `parent`table add

```
@property
def has_grandchildren(self):
    return any(child.grandchildren for child in self.children)
```

you can then get a list of all parents_with_no_grandchildren by some form of

```
parents = session.query(Parent).all()
parents_with_no_grandchildren = [parent for parent in parents if not parent.has_grandchildren]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution. By modifying the property to just be `return [child for child in self.children if child.grandchildren]` the property does meet the requirement to return a list of `child` objects that have at least one `grandchild` object associated with it. My concern with this solution is if the number of child objects is large and the number of child objects with a grandchild is small this iteration becomes very costly, especially if the property is called many times. By configuring a relationship I was hoping to reduce the iteration cost.